# Найти подстроку в строке QString

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt, строки, qstring

У меня есть строка, типа `QString`, которая содержит запись вида *Some text COM5 some_text*, число после *COM* в диапазоне от 1 до 255. Как мне взять подстроку *COM123*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь классом [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.htm).

Для вашей задачи, сформируем простое регулярное выражение вида:

```
COM\d{1,}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int comPos = s.indexOf("COM");
int comEndPos = s.indexOf(" ", comPos);
QString subStr = s.mid(comPos, comEndPos - comPos);
```

Только тут нет никаких проверок, нужно проверять результаты функций, а то мало ли у вас в строке не будет подстроки "COM" и т.д. и т.п.